# How do I replace the checkboxes in my C# excel export to ones and zeros?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel, checkbox

In a C# application I created a `GridView` dynamically and exported it to Excel. The issue that I am having is that since three fields are Bit columns in SQL they export as checkboxes and not ones and zeros. I have done some searching on google for similar issues and found [this article](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/check-box.html) this solution. However, this will not work out since right or left clicking on the object only checks or unchecks the box.

I have also tried to find information on how to export the bit fields as 1's and 0's from C# and have not been able to find anything. Here is my export script:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(writer);
GridView gridView = new GridView();
gridView.DataSource = sdsResults;
gridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
gridView.DataBind();
gridView.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#003c74");
gridView.HeaderRow.Style.Add("color", "#ffffff");
for (int i = 0; i < gridView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = gridView.Rows[i];

            //Change Color back to white
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

            //Apply text style to each Row
            row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");

            //Apply style to Individual Cells of Alternating Row
            if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;
            }

            foreach(TableCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if(cell.HasControls() == true)
                {
                  if(cell.Controls[0].GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.Ui.WebControls.CheckBox")
                   {
                       CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)cell.Controls[0];
                        if(chk.Checked)
                        {
                           cell.Text = "1";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cell.Text = "0";
                        }
                   }
                }
            }
        }
gridView.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
htmlWriter.Close();

Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=myfile.xls");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.Write(writer.ToString());
Response.End();
Response.End();
```

Comment: so you mean: if the checkbox is checked, than it should be exported to sql as a 1 and otherwise a 0? your question is a bit unclear

Comment: @Koen Yes. I apologize for being unclear. I tried to explain as best I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the for loop, you can do something like this:

```
foreach(TableCell cell in row.Cells)
 {
   if(cell.HasControls() == true)
    {
      if(cell.Controls[0].GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox")
       {
           CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)cell.Controls[0];
           if(chk.Checked)
            {
               cell.Text = "1";
            }
           else{
                cell.Text = "0";
               }
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: `if(chk.Checked == true)` really? Better check `if((chk.Checked == true) == true)` to be sure...

Comment: @Corak XD, i laughed to hard. But yes you are right it is unneccesary code.

Comment: But seriously, if you want to know, if a variable (i.e. a control) is of a certain type or subtype (or "is convertible to"), you can use [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/scekt9xw.aspx). Like: `if (cell.Controls[0] is System.Web.Ui.WebControls.CheckBox)` without having to take the slow detour via `ToString()`. And you can shorten the innermost `if` by using the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ty67wk28.aspx). Like: `cell.Text = ((CheckBox)cell.Controls[0]).Checked ? "1" : "0";`. ^_^

Comment: @Corak sh*t thats way shorter, anyhow i am a starting programmer and will just stick with my newbie thousands ifs ;). First basics, than the harder stuff.

Comment: @Koen I updated the code and put in in my original question but i am still getting textboxes in those fields instead of 1's and 0's

Comment: You can also "chain" the first two `ifs` together with the [&& operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/2a723cdk.aspx). Btw. `if(cell.HasControls() == true)` again ^^. Like: `if(cell.HasControls() && cell.Controls[0] is System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)`. You won't get an error accessing `Controls[0]` because `cell.HasControls()` will be checked first and if that returns `false`, then everything after the `&&` will not be evaluated.

Comment: @Skullomania the if statement had a typo Ui, instead of UI.Changed it in my example

Answer (score 0):

If you're building the datasource with a SQL query then CAST the bit columns as int or varchar. If that can't be done try defining the GridView columns with desired data types before assigning the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void btnXlsExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    gvStandard.AllowPaging = false;
    gvStandard.DataBind();
    for (int i = 0; i <= gvStandard.Rows.Count - 1; i++) {
        GridViewRow row = gvStandard.Rows(i);
        foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells) {
            if (cell.HasControls() == true) {
                if (cell.Controls(0).GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox") {
                    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)cell.Controls(0);
                    if (chk.Checked) {
                        cell.Text = "True";
                    } else {
                        cell.Text = "False";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    gvStandard.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
    gvStandard.RenderControl(hw);
    Response.Output.Write(sw);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Protected Sub btnXlsExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnXlsExport.Click

```
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls")
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Dim sw As New StringWriter()
    Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    gvStandard.AllowPaging = False
    gvStandard.DataBind()
    For i As Integer = 0 To gvStandard.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim row As GridViewRow = gvStandard.Rows(i)
        For Each cell As TableCell In row.Cells
            If cell.HasControls() = True Then
                If cell.Controls(0).[GetType]().ToString() = "System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox" Then
                    Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(cell.Controls(0), CheckBox)
                    If chk.Checked Then
                        cell.Text = "True"
                    Else
                        cell.Text = "False"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    gvStandard.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF")
    gvStandard.RenderControl(hw)
    Response.Output.Write(sw)
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be C#, as the question is, which is unfortunate.

Comment: sorry this is vb code... C# code is also given. Thank you